# How to setup Python IDE make auto complete work?

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, pycharm, ida

I want to write IDAPython scripts and plugins. The problem is to get my Python IDE (PyCharm) to resolve the imports correctly and therefore get code completion correct.

Here is an example. I want that code completion works for IDAPython commands like:

```
ea = ScreenEA()
```

or

```
ea = idc.get_screen_ea()
```

Here is what I did. I downloaded [IDAPython](https://github.com/idapython/src/tree/master/python) and put the source in my Python projects source folder.

[image]

I also copied the python folder from the IDA install directory into my Python projects source directory.

[image]

It turns out, that Pycharm cannot resolve the functions correctly.

[image]

[image]

**How to setup Python IDE make auto complete work?**

Answer (score 0):

As long as the IDAPython files show up in you Pycharm project, or are in the same folder, you simply need to import the file you want to use.

So for your idc.get_screen_ea() example, as long as you have this at the top of your python file you are working on:

```
 #import idc
```

Then you will get suggestions for anything involving idc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I took for PyCharm Windows version. First create an venv based project with the python version match your IDA python version.

File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter

Click setting icon, select `Show All...`

[image]

Select the interpreter you currently use, click `Show paths for the selected interpreter`

[image]

At the popup window, add your `%IDA_INSTALL_PATH%\python`

Then you can use PyCharm IDE features to write IDA python plugin.